# error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/content' with config ''

Tags: android

I run my project, display:

> error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/content' with config ''.
>   Message{kind=ERROR, text=error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/content' with config ''., sources=[/Users/bobzheng/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-26.1.0.aar/805cd07c22a7f63b737aa31bb4d52686/res/values/values.xml:246:5-69], original message=, tool name=Optional.of(AAPT)}

Can you help me?

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

before:

build.gradle

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0-alpha1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.0-alpha2'
```

After:

build.gradle

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0-alpha1'
```

remove 
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.0-alpha2'

It is OK.

Comment: remove ConstraintLayout

Answer (score 0):

You should use `support library` version < `26`,

for example: `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1`

Comment: I have changed it, but it still be err.

Comment: I have upload a screen photo.